# functools.singledispatchmethod raises IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, dispatch

What is wrong with how I applied the `functools.singledispatchmethod` decorator?

```python
import functools

class K:
    @functools.singledispatchmethod
    def m(self, iobj:object):
        print("root")

    @m.register
    def m_from_str(self, istr:str):
        print('string')

    @m.register
    def m_from_object(self, ilist:list):
        print('list')

obj = K()

obj.m()
```

The Error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    method = self.dispatcher.dispatch(args[0].__class__)
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Well, you didn't pass an argument, and that method needs one...

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing `obj.m()` we write something like `obj.m("hello word")`